# Is there a problem with importing a SWF movie made in AS3 into a SWF movie made in AS2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I haven't tried yet but am curious if I should even bother.

I have a legacy AS2 swf that I don't want to rewrite in AS3 but I need to improve upon it to play video, and I'd prefer to use the AS3 video playing mechanisms.

Ideally I can build an AS3 movie that just takes a string param of the movie location and plays it.  I'd load this AS3 swf into my AS2 movie and pass in the strings for the urls as necessary.

If the MOST important thing is expediency... is my best options to

**A** get a job as a short order cook at the local Greek Diner
**B** build the movie player using the less fancy AS2 video playback component
**C** proceed with my intentions as planned utilizing whatever advice I gather from this post

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVM2 (AS3) movies cannot be loaded into AVM1 (AS1/2) movies. The inverse is possible, however.

While a short order cook would be fun for a while, I think you might enjoy an AS2 movie player :P

Answer (score 1):

get a job as a short order cook at the local Greek Diner

Comment: I see you only have 3 experience points, so, I'm up voting your answer even though you didn't offer me any specific additional info that I might find useful.  Examples include *Only if you look really good in checkered pants* or *Only if you promise not to try to import your grandmother's tsadziki into their modern souvlaki*